# Call a method of an Activity from a class

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have Activity named `BarcodeScanActivity`which has a method **`OnScanDataPass`**. I want to access this method from a non Activity class (Normal Calss).

```
public class BarcodeScanActivity : Activity, EMDKManager.IEMDKListener
{
     static IScanDataPass _scanDataPass;

     public void OnScanDataPass(IScanDataPass scanDataPass)
     {
         _scanDataPass = scanDataPass;
     }
}
```

below is my class

```
public class ScanCode_Android : IScanCode, IScanDataPass
{
        static Context context = Application.Context;
        private Intent intent = new Intent(context,typeof(BarcodeScanActivity));
        private BarcodeScanActivity scan = new BarcodeScanActivity();

        public ScanCode_Android()
        {
            context.StartActivity(intent);
            scan.OnScanDataPass(this);
        }
}
```

Above code snippet shows the method i tried.
How do I call a method in an activity from a normal class?
How can I do it with Intent?

Comment: Have you solved your problem? Does my answer work for you?

Comment: @JoeLvMSFT No its yet to be solved..
you solution takes the activity from parameters..
since i need default constructor to be implemented i cannot pass parameters..
and i need new activity to be run in background. it shouldn't pop up new user interface.

Comment: By `i need new activity to be run in background`, you mean that you want a activity which won't been seen when you start it? If so, you can create a activity which size is 1*1.

Comment: yes thats what I want..

Comment: Hi, I have updated my answer, please test.

Comment: @JoeLvMSFT thanks for your valuable time..
I have solved it anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You can not instantiate an Activity manually, the instance of Activity will be instantiated by System, and its process is complex.

---

You can pass the instance of Activity to your Normal Class to achieve your goal:

```
public class ScanCode_Android : IScanCode, IScanDataPass 
{ 
        BarcodeScanActivity mContext ;

        public ScanCode_Android(BarcodeScanActivity context) 
        {   
            this.mContext=context;
            Intent intent = new Intent(context,typeof(BarcodeScanActivity));
            context.StartActivity(intent);
            context.OnScanDataPass(this);
        } 
}
```

---

> How can I do it with Intent?

You need use [Context](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html) to deal with it. Like [StartActivity, StartService...](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html).

> How do I call a method in an activity from a normal class?

Like the above codes, pass Activity to Normal class.

### Update:

You can create one pixel Activity to avoid the Activity to been seen.

`OnePiexlActivity`:

```
[Activity(Label = "OnePiexlActivity",Theme = "@style/OnePixelActivity")]
public class OnePiexlActivity : Activity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Window.SetGravity(GravityFlags.Left | GravityFlags.Top);
        WindowManagerLayoutParams layoutParams=  Window.Attributes;
        layoutParams.X = 0;
        layoutParams.Y = 0;
        layoutParams.Height = 1;
        layoutParams.Width = 1;
        Window.Attributes=layoutParams;
        Android.Util.Log.Error("lv","111111111111");
    
    }
}
```

`style`:

```
<style name="OnePixelActivity" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar">
  <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
</style>
```